# how to access library into the verifone vx520 terminal

Tags: c, verifone

I am working with some libraries using Windows OS, and nmake.  The terminal is not accepting these libraries and I am getting an error when I try to compile the code.

The libraries I need to include are

```
#include "iso8583.h"
#include "iso8583_defs_1993.h"
#include "output.h" // for 'DL_OUTPUT_Hex'
#include "appl8583.h"
```

When I compile the code, it's showing the error

> no any input source file "iso8583_defs_1993.h"

Comment: Please provide more information: at what point are you getting an error? What is the error? Where do these header files live/where did they come from? What are you using to build your program (for example, are you using nmake)?  The more you can tell us about your specific problem, the more likely we'll be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Regarding "...but terminal is not accepting these libraries and generating error , even the code is not compiling at windows also."  So you are getting an error at compile time, yes?  What is the error?  My first guess is that your make file is not referencing the directories where these files live, but it's impossible to say with such little information.

Comment: `and please tell me the way to copy the whole code over stak overflow.` Unless your code base is VERY short, that's not how this site is meant to work.  Rather, you should just share the parts that are directly relevant to your problem.  To add code blocks, indent the code 4 spaces.  You can copy and paste and then use the `{}` icon to do that for you.

Comment: I've made some substantial edits to your question in an attempt to really focus on your actual problem.  Feel free to roll back these edits if you feel I removed something important.  Also, if you click `edit`, you can see how the formatting is done to achieve the look for quote blocks. You can use that to include more code, as necessary.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?  I'm curious to know if my answer was helpful to you. @Manish T

Answer (score 1):

Based on your statement

> now when i compile the code then its showing the error no any input source file "iso8583_defs_1993.h"

it sounds to me like your make file is not referencing the necessary directories.

Let's take a look at your make file.  You will call `vrxcc` a few times and each time you have to pass it several arguments.  Let's start where you call it to compile (probably at the bottom of the make file).  Let me share one such line from my make file.  (NOTE: This is normally all on one line, but I've broken it up and added c-style comments (//) to explain what's going on.  I realize `//` comments don't work in make files, but they are very readable here)

```
-$(EVOSDK)\bin\vrxcc  // invokes the compiler
-c                    // compile only
$(COptions)           // my variable that passes compiler options 
$(Includes)           // my variable that passes all the directories to include
-o $(ObjDir)\$(ProjectName).o        // output the object file here
$(SrcDir)\$(ProjectName).c           // the input file (to compile)
-e"-" | "$(EVOTOOLS)fmterrorARM.exe" // where to send error output
```

(See `%evosdk%\..\Docs\DOC00303_Verix_eVo_Volume_III Operating_System Programming_Tools_Reference_Manual.doc` for more info on compiling and linking)

Now, each part of that command has significance, but for the purposes of this discussion, the one we need to focus on is `$(Includes)`.  Let me show you what that consists of for me:

```
Includes = -I$(AppIncludes) //Where AppIncludes  = .\include 
             $(SDKIncludes) //Where SDKIncludes  = -I$(EVOSDK)\include
             $(ACTIncludes) //Where ACTIncludes  = -I$(EVOACT)include
             $(VMACIncludes)//Where VMACIncludes = -I$(EVOVMAC)include
             $(VCSIncludes) //Where VCSIncludes  = -I$(EVOVCS)include
```

Any time you want to `#include` something, the directory where that file lives has to be passed to the compiler using the `-I` flag.  For example, if you are trying to `#include "iso8583.h"` from the ACT library, then you must have `-I$(EVOACT)include` as part of your `$(Includes)`.  If you don't, then you'll get an error saying that it can't find the file you are trying to use:

> "error : #5: cannot open source input file "iso8583_defs_1993.h": No such file or directory"

The reason I was asking `Where do these header files live/where did they come from?` in my comments above was because I'm assuming `iso8583_defs_1993.h` is a custom library or code file that you have brought with you.  If that's the case, then wherever that file lives, you need to make sure it is part of the `$(Includes)` as well.

Once everything has been compiled, we still have to link everything together.  (NOTE: Since nmake uses file changes as dependencies, the linking part will likely be positioned higher in the make file than the compile part.)  I only have 1 linking line and it looks like this:

```
$(EVOSDK)\bin\vrxcc $(COptions) $(AppObjects) $(Libs) -o $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).out
```

- `$(COptions)` is the same as what we passed to the compiler
- `$(AppObjects)` is my variable.  I have several .c files and each one gets compiled to an object file.  This represents each of those `.o` files
- `$(Libs)` any external libraries you want to include.  For me, this is defined as `Libs = $(ACTLibraries)\act2000.a` BUT if you are trying to import custom libraries (without source code--if you have source code, then it will be part of `AppObjects`) then you will have to add them here. **Note that your library will need to be compiled for an ARM-11 processor or it won't work**.  If you have the source code, you may want to add it to your `AppObjects` instead.
- `-o $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).out` just specifies the output file